# Which tool and framework to use RestAPI Automation Testing?

Tags: api, jmeter, testng, rest-assured, frisby.js

I am looking for RestAPI automation tool which should be open source tool.
Not getting which tool and framework should go.

Can anyone suggest for me good tool and framework for API automation testing?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi You can use Jmeter for API testing . Check out the videos in the [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2S-AxLfg-0) Jmeter can be integrated well with Jenkins and that can be used to automate the API testing using Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your requirements and your skills.

1. The most obvious choice would be [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/), it normally doesn't require any developer background and has limited [load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html).
2. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) can be also used for API testing, it has [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) to design the test, [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to set pass/fail criteria and if you will need to run tests in multithreaded manner - JMeter is designed for load testing. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) for more details.
3. Any programming language / library / framework which can send HTTP requests and has good support of XML or JSON or both. However it assumes some underlying programming language knowledge, besides when it comes to client SSL certificates, protocol-based and other security types it can be a headache. The most popular framework seems to be [REST-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured), it's Java-based, if you're not comfortable with Java you can try searching for equivalent for programming language(s) you know better.

Comment: Can we use Rest-assured with other languages? How to start with Rest-assured for automation.

Answer (score 0):

You Can go for SOAPUI opensource https://www.soapui.org/

You can create your own framework , using groovy or Java language, can use lot of plugins

Soaupi has lot options , easy learning curve ,and lot of online support , and large userbase.

Soap UI scripts can be maintained easily.

Soapui scripts can run through , JUNIT,TESTNG, ANT, GRADLE, MAVEN  and reports can be generated.

For load testing/mini stress on your REST API, its easy ,just right click on existing test case and add to load test .

All the best , Happy Testing